# SysML/UML Simulating a nested State Machine Diagram in an Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, simulation, state-machine, activity-diagram, sysml

I am still new to SysML and UML and the simulation of those diagrams. I am using Cameo Systems Modeler 19.0.

Context: My problem concerns the continuous simulation of an activity diagram in which a state machine diagram is nested. In the activity diagram I have a Call Behaviour Action which calls the state machine diagram. After this call behaviour action there are other actions to be executed. When I simulate the activity diagram the simulation switches to the called state machine diagram without any problem. Also the simulation of this state machine diagram is fully functional.

Now onto my problem: When I finalize the simulation of the state machine diagram by choosing states, path and their triggers so that I get to the Final State Node, it terminates the simulation of the State Machine Diagram (as expected). **But the simulation won't continue executing in the parenting activity diagram.**

Am I doing something wrong? Are you not supposed to be able to simulate these kinds of diagrams nested like that? Am I expecting something of Cameo Systems Modeler, that this programm just can't do?

Thanks for your help! If my description is not sufficient, I will happily provide a .mdzip as a minimal example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definetely is a bug. I issued a problem and the support team identified it as such.

Update: it has been fixed

Comment: Does anyone know whether I can get Cameo Systems Modeler to switch over to a nested activity diagram, then switch back to the diagram from which that behavior was called, during simulation?

Answer (score 1):

In UML and SysML state machines, reaching a termination pseudo state means that the scope to which the behaviour that is defined by the state machine is terminated (when it is on the top scope in the state machine diagram). This is treated in different tools diffently. Some tools use (by default or always) the state machines as mester for simulation and when the topmost state machine enters a termination pseudo state the simulation is stoped, even if it was triggered from an activity.

There is a further kind of end pseudo state for state machines, it is called an exit point. Exit points trigger that the current scope is left. And as you dont want to stop your simulation this is waht you could use. An exit point is denoted by a hallow circle with cross.

Thought: Plenty of tools deviate from whats defined in UML and SysML especially when simulating dynamic behaviours. So there might be some special options in Cameo that possibly need some consideration. One solution to some of the tools is that you create a master state machine, that triggers your master activity.

Comment: "reaching a termination pseudo state means that the whole system is terminated" : no, only the enclosing state/region, and in the present case where it seems the state machine is finished that finishes the calling *call behavior action* and only it, so the activity can continue if there are edge after it

Comment: ok thanks for your answers! the thing is, if I replace the Final State with an exit point, the model won't simulate, because the exit point is apperently not suported: The Error message is: ERROR: Exit Point Pseudo State is not supported in the execution. May there be another way to get to the result I want in any other way in Cameo?

Comment: @e_frog the termination point was the right choice. Just are you sure all the state machine is ended ? do you have sub/machine/state/region etc and at least one is not ended to explain ? else this is a bug/limitation of your tool

Comment: @Bruno, you are right, I corrected it. Typically this is very tool specific behaviour. Idont know Cameo, but in Rhapsody and some others I worked with the (former and newly proposed) ways to overcome this.

Comment: @Bruno Yes it is fully ended. I replicated the described behavior with a really simple stm (only Initial State, an example state & Final State and two transitions without a signal inbetween)

Comment: @e_frog so probably a bug of the tool (or an option you did not see), look at their FAQ and forum to know if this is a known problem else do not be afraid to contact them to signal the bug, nothing worst than bug detected by users but not reported (I am well placed to know that ^^)

Comment: @bruno I reported it as an issue. If something comes out of it and I remember this post, i will definitely give an update on the matter! Thanks so far!

Comment: @bruno it definetely is a bug. I issued a problem and the support team identified it as such.